# Replace JSON values

Tags: json

It is my first time talking about `JSON` and I need some help (sorry if I make some mistake).

I have datas in the MySql database with strange values `(ex. è - à - ù - ò.....)` and when I have back the response from JSON my field result null.

Follow you can see the code I'm using!
Could somebody help me how to replace this letters or fixing the problem.

THANK YOU!

I get my datas phrased

```
{"items":
 {
  "id":"305",
  "title":"Il manipolatore",
  "description":null
 }
 ....
}
```

This is my code:

```
var serviceURL = "app/testE/services/";
var employees;

$('#employeeListPage').bind('pageinit', function(event) {
getEmployeeList();
});

function getEmployeeList() {
$.getJSON(serviceURL + 'getemployees.php', function(data) {
$('#employeeList li').remove();
employees = data.items;
$.each(employees, function(index, employee) {
$('#employeeList').append('<li><a href="employeedetails.html?id=' + employee.id + '">' + '<img src="' + employee.img + '" width="80px" height="80px" />' +
'<h4>' + employee.title + '</h4>' +
'<p>' + employee.description + '</p>' +
'</a></li>');
});
$('#employeeList').listview('refresh');
});
}
```

Comment: Make sure you set request encoding correctly or, if you have access to DB software, make it encode anything non-ASCII in `\u` notation.

Comment: I'm not using a DB access but MySql. I wonder if there is a solution to replace special carachters (è ò à  ù) coding my js page for example insert some code before description. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Use **$.ajax()** rather than $.getJSON() and then set the charset to utf-8.

http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/